# nginx upstream config in a separate file

Tags: nginx

I have site on nginx on 10.0.0.1 with simple config file:

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  server.com;

    location / {
        root /www;
        index index.html;
    }
```

Also I want to redirect requests to http://10.0.0.1/app1 to 3 servers with the same app on port 8888, like:

http://10.0.0.1/app1 -> http://10.0.0.(2,3,4):8888/app1

so I have to add to my default.conf such configuration for balancing:

```
upstream app1 {
   server 10.0.0.2:8888;
   server 10.0.0.3:8888;
   server 10.0.0.4:8888;
}

server {
   listen 80;

   location /app1/ {
      rewrite ^/app1^/ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://app1;
   }
}
```

but I want to keep this balancing config in a separate file - app1.conf.

If I have this two config files in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ folder I can only open URL http://10.0.0.1/

But when I open http://10.0.0.1/app1 I get error 404 because of default.conf it tries to find app1 in /www and even not tries to check app1.conf for balancing rules.
So it seems than works only default.conf config file. 
How can fix it?

Comment: I'd say the reason is you got two server blocks with the same listen port. It has nothing to do with the two config files/directories.

Comment: thank you for your advice. but it seems I can't use location directive outside the server block, and if I change port number in app1.conf - nginx starts listen on that port which is does not meet my conditions - I need open URL  "http://10.0.0.1/app1"

Answer (score 4):

The `upsteam` part needs to be in the `http` block anyways, which resides in your nginx.conf/default.conf.
For just the location block you pobably can use:

*default.conf*

```
http {
...
    upstream app1 {
       server 10.0.0.2:8888;
       server 10.0.0.3:8888;
       server 10.0.0.4:8888;
    }
...
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  server.com;

    include /path/to/app1.conf;

    location / {
        root /www;
        index index.html;
    }
...
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*;
...
}
```

*app1.conf*

```
location /app1/ {
  rewrite ^/app1^/ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://app1;
}
```

Edit the path for the `include` in the default.conf.

**Edit:**
Actually I made a mistake here. The directives of nginx are hierarchical. In the documentation you can find where you can use which block. The `server` block needs to be in the `http` block. The `location` block can be in `server` and `location` blocks.
Depending which block you are in you can use `include` to import blocks in that specific context.
So using `include` in the `server` block you can include app specific `location` blocks but not `server` blocks. That is because the `server` block can only reside in the `http` block.
I hope this helps to clarify your situtation.

**Edit2:**
From your comment i just saw that the regex in the rewrite is probably wrong.

*app1.conf*

```
location /app1/ {
  rewrite ^/[^\/]+)(/.*) $1 break;
  proxy_pass http://app1;
}
```

Comment: That rewrite is going to remove /app1/ from the original url /app1/some/more/. If you don't want anything to be cut off you should remove it.

Comment: thanks, I've just checked this. when I have app1.conf with

    location /app1/ {
        rewrite ^/app1^/ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://app1;
    }

I cant restart nginx, I receive error:

    /etc/init.d/nginx restart
    [....] Restarting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    failed!

and in error.log:

   2017/03/03 15:29:05 [emerg] 21787#0: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/app1.conf:1

Comment: UPD:
I've fixed this issue - need rename app1.conf to just app1 (without .conf)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Create a file `/etc/nginx/upstream.conf`

   ```
   server 10.0.0.2:8888;
   server 10.0.0.3:8888;
   server 10.0.0.4:8888;
   ```
2. Change your config to:

   ```
   upstream app1 {
       include /etc/nginx/upstream.conf;
   }

   server {
       listen 80;

       location /app1/ {
       rewrite ^/app1^/ /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://app1;
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I checked this variant, but I definitely need keep all configuration for upstream in separate file - in this way I can disable this configuration by renaming this file.
but seems it is not possible, so I'll go with include directives.

Comment: It fails on 1.19.0 as `nginx: [emerg] directive "server" has no opening "{"  in /etc/nginx/upstream.conf:1`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can import NGINX from different files using the following patterns.

1. `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/stream.conf;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/http.conf;
```

2.1. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/stream.conf`

```
stream {

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream/*.conf; # Include Upstream Block first.
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/stream/*.conf;

}
```

2.2. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/http.conf`

```
http {
  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  sendfile            on;
  tcp_nopush          on;
  tcp_nodelay         on;
  keepalive_timeout   65;
  types_hash_max_size 4096;

  include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream/*.conf; # Include Upstream Block first.
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/http/*.conf;

}
```

3.1. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream/application.domain.com.conf`

```
upstream application.domain.com {
  server 192.168.0.1:80;
  server 192.168.0.2:80;
  server 192.168.0.3:80;
}

upstream ssl-application.domain.com {
  server 192.168.0.1:443;
  server 192.168.0.2:443;
  server 192.168.0.3:443;
}
```

4.1. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/stream/application.domain.com.conf`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  proxy_pass application.domain.com;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443;

  # SSL Pass-through Technique. Passing SSL Encrypt/Decrypt to Back-End Application.
  proxy_pass ssl-application.domain.com;
}
```

4.2. `/etc/nginx/conf.d/http/application.domain.com.conf`

```
server {
  listen      80;
  listen      [::]:80;
  server_name _;
  root        /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://application.domain.com;
  }

}

server {
  listen      443;
  listen      [::]:443;
  server_name _;
  root        /usr/share/nginx/html;

  # Handle SSL Certificate here.

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # Either SSL Terminate or not. For SSL Passthrough you need to config
    # via Stream block - Layer 4 TCP Protocol.
    proxy_pass https://ssl-application.domain.com;
  }

}
```